# Replacing a fragment deletes another fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm having an issue with my fragments but not sure why. I have two fragments on the main activity. One side (right) has a spinner over the fragment, in that fragment I replace what fragment is shown with the spinner. The left side shows a list view with data been shown using an array adapter.

The problem is, whenever I replace a fragment on the left side, the right side fragment disappears and I don't know why it's doing that.

This is the code for my spinner replacing the left side fragment:

```
personSelection.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {

                personType = "Student";

                StudentFragment studentFrag = StudentFragment.newInstance();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.form, studentFrag)
                        .commit();

            } else if (position == 1) {

                personType = "Teacher";

                TeacherFragment teacherFrag = TeacherFragment.newInstance();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.form, teacherFrag)
                        .commit();

            } else if (position == 2) {

                personType = "Administrator";

                AdminFragment adminFrag = AdminFragment.newInstance();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.form, adminFrag)
                        .commit();

            } // end if/else

        } // end personSelection

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

    }); // end selection
```

The right side fragment gets refreshed using a button next to the spinner to show the new added data to the array list, that's the only time that fragment is been used.

A visual to show what I mean.

- App working fine when started:

[image]

- After spinner is selected: (the refresh button doesn't work either after this)

[image]

This is the xml for the main activity:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/person_spinner"
        android:entries="@array/child"
        android:layout_width="170dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync"
        android:drawableTint="#000000"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
    android:name="com....StudentFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:id="@+id/form"
        tools:layout="@layout/student_fragment" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:name="com....DetailFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    android:id="@+id/frame_detail"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to replace both (left and right fragments) dynamically. Don't define any fragments in your xml layout. Instead, use 2 FrameLayouts as the containers for your fragments and attach required fragments dynamically in your code only, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I shouldn't be trying to replace a fragment, this removes it and messed with the whole layout of the main activity. So what I did was, create all the fragments together in the main and add them in relative layouts inside a linear layout. On the onCreate method I just changed their visibility to show the one I wanted and hide the others depending on the spinner choice. Now the whole app works without any problems.